# solving $T(n)= 2T(n/2) + 5$ using master theorem

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I have some questions regarding solving this recurrence relation T(n)=2T(n/2) + 5 using master theorem.

$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 5$$

I managed to get a time complexity of Θ (n log n) as my answer using master theorem case 2 but I'm quite sure its incorrect, never come across a integer on its own = f(n) so far and am unsure how to handle it, would appreciate some clarification on this matter.

Comment: Check out this document. It seems the binary traversal case on page 4 is what you are looking for : www.cse.unt.edu/~tarau/teaching/cf1/Master%20theorem.pdf

Comment: Ah i see now, I read that but didn't look at the table at the bottom. Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome. The table is obscurely hidden, fair enough.